# Google Sheets Apps script does not have permission to perform that action

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple Google Sheets function that uses the Calendar App.

```
function getAllOwnedCalendars() {
  return CalendarApp.getAllOwnedCalendars().map(cal => cal.getName());
}
```

I can run it from the script debugger after consenting to the access.

I then call it from the container sheet using

```
=getAllOwnedCalendars()
```

and get:

```
Exception: The script does not have permission to perform that action.
Required permissions:
 (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar || 
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly ||
  https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds)
```

I have added these scopes to appsettings.json:

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
    "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds"
  ],
  ...
}
```

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes

I've reproduced it in 2 mins in a new sheet and even logged out of all my other Google accounts in case that had any bearing.

What am I missing?

Comment: when you said `when I call it from the Google Sheets container`, can you elaborate further on this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem

Comment: I've updated the with an example call from Google Sheets. It really is that trivial and takes 2 min to repro -- for me at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written a function to serve as a "Custom function" - `=getAllOwnedCalendars()`

Custom functions are VERY limited in the script services that are available to them. Details of [App script services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services) are in the documentation. Calendar services are NOT available.

The documentation adds two further points that may assist the OP:

**Error Messages**

- "If your custom function throws the error message `You do not have permission to call X service.`, the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function."

**Workaround**

- "To use a service other than those listed, create a custom menu that runs an Apps Script function instead of writing a custom function. A function that is triggered from a menu will ask the user for authorization if necessary and can consequently use all Apps Script services."

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer and link to the docs!
I had assumed that the container would be authorised once the function was.
I've successfully added a custom menu to call an update function using a named range.